# Adding Existing Controls to a New Form in PowerApps & They are not Coming Under the New Form

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I have a scenario that I would like to get answers to a few questions. Please refer to the below details.

I have created a new Canvas App. This App is an **Organization's IT Help Desk**. In that App, I have 4 screens. My datasource is a **SharePoint Online List**.

1. User Screen - New Request Form (Built using Textboxes, labels, drop-downs, People Picker, Calendar Control, Buttons
2. User Screen - All Requests (Pending/Approved/Executed/On Hold)
3. Manager Approval Screens - For the relevant 'Head of Departments'
4. IT Team Screen - For the IT Team.

When I was designing the First Screen, I created the controls. However, I noticed that I **haven't added a Form and after creating the controls**, I tried to **add the previously created controls to the new Form** and it was unsuccessful because they are **not coming under the new form control**.

Then I added the **SharePoint Online List as the datasource**. Then the controls were auto-generated. Those **generated controls come under the Form**.

Is it possible to **add the controls I previously created under the new Form control**? **instead of the autogenerated controls**? The reason is I have **done extensive UI modifications** to the **controls I have previously created**.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Best regards,
Chiranthaka